# How to concat 2 strings in pywin32 (excel) in a range?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I use win32 in python to automaticly adjust import files. I'm trying to take 2 cellvalues and concat them into a third value, which gets written into the other worksheet.

I get the error message that "+" is not a valid opperand within a range 'TypeNone'. How can i fix this problem?

Tried to use globals() and str and make a function with no result.

```py
import win32com.client as win32
import os

os.listdir('.')
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
file = "April.xlsx"
dirpath = r'C:\Users\admin\Dropbox\Python\\'

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(dirpath + file)
sox = wb.Worksheets('sheet1')
mun = wb.Worksheets('sheet2')

# variables
range = sox.Range("A3:A515")
x = 3 #skipping first 3 headers

for i in range:
    valueA = sox.Cells(x, 12)
    valueB = sox.Cells(x, 13)
    mun.Cells(x, 6).Value = valueA + valueB

    print(x)
    if x < 515:
        x += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the file content, here are my assumptions:

1. The fail point is the line:

   mun.Cells(x, 6).Value = valueA + valueB
2. The value type contained in valueA and valueB are to be treated as type str (based on your comment "Tried to use globals() and str"

I'd guess that one of the cells is empty and is being interpreted as a value of None. If this is the case, try this:

```
mun.Cells(x, 6).Value = str(valueA or '') + str(valueB or '')
```

(those are two single quotes, not a double-quote)